# pandas groupby index: nan conflicts or take only value

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'm working with some data via `pandas` which can have some inconsistencies I need to handle. The data is a time series of values:

```
                     A     B      C
YYYY MM DD hh mm                                
2017 8  20 23 0      1   2.0    NaN
              10     2   4.0    NaN
              20     3   6.0    NaN
              30     4   8.0    NaN
...                ...   ...    ...
2019 6  4  10 10   100   100    NaN
              20   200   102    NaN
              30   300   104    NaN
              40   400   106    NaN
              50   500   108      0
```

The inconsistency the data can have is multiple entries for the same `["YYYY", "MM", "DD", "hh", "mm"]` index. In most cases, the values at that time are are identical so I can use `df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")` to drop all rows with the same index and column values.

However, there are index collisions where the values are not identical or a non-nan value is only present in one of the rows. The behaviour I'm after is:

For duplicate indices, on a per-column bases:

1. If only one non-nan value: use that.
2. If all nan values: use nan.
3. If all the same (non-nan) value: use that.
4. If non-equal (non-nan) value: use nan.

For example (is a simplified DataFrame):

```
     A      B    C
0    1    2.0  NaN
1    2    NaN  NaN
1  100  500.0  NaN
2    3    6.0  NaN
2  200    6.0  NaN
3  300    8.0  NaN
3  300    NaN  5.0
3  300    NaN  NaN
4  400  106.0  NaN
```

Should result in:

```
       A      B    C
0    1.0    2.0  NaN
1    NaN  500.0  NaN
2    NaN    6.0  NaN
3  300.0    8.0  5.0
4  400.0  106.0  NaN
```

I tried to solve this in a couple of methods, but they were both horrendously slow on the dataset size.

current slow solutions (you may need to scroll the code snippet window):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        dict(A=1, B=2.0, C=None),
        dict(A=2, B=None, C=None),
        dict(A=100, B=500, C=None),
        dict(A=3, B=6.0, C=None),
        dict(A=200, B=6.0, C=None),
        dict(A=300, B=8.0, C=None),
        dict(A=300, B=None, C=5.0),
        dict(A=300, B=None, C=None),
        dict(A=400, B=106, C=None),
    ],
    index=[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
)


# SLOW SOLUTION 1
def canonical(colum_values):
    candidates = colum_values.dropna().unique()
    if len(candidates) == 1:
        return candidates[0]
    else:
        return np.nan


solution_1 = df.groupby(df.index).aggregate(canonical)


# SLOW & UGLY SOLUTION 2
def solve_2(df):
    df = df.copy()

    for dupe in df.index[df.index.duplicated(keep="first")]:
        for column in df.columns:
            values = df[df.index == dupe][column]

            if len(values.dropna().unique()) == 1:
                df.loc[df.index == dupe, column] = values.dropna().iloc[0]
            else:
                df.loc[df.index == dupe, column] = np.nan
    
    # duplicate rows should all now share the same value, so just keep one.
    df.drop_duplicates(keep="first", inplace=True)

    return df


solution_2 = solve_2(df)
```

Looking for any improvements on these to get better performance on large datasets.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you miss the fourth condition: `4. If non-equal (non-nan) value: use nan.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group` the dataframe on `level=0` and aggregate using **[`.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)** to get the first `non-nan` value per `level=0` group then **[`.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)** the values in columns where there are more than one unique values per `level=0` group :

```
g = df.groupby(level=0)
g.first().mask(g.nunique().gt(1))
```

**Details:**

```
g.first()

     A      B    C
0    1    2.0  NaN
1    2  500.0  NaN
2    3    6.0  NaN
3  300    8.0  5.0
4  400  106.0  NaN

g.nunique().gt(1)

       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
4  False  False  False
```

**Result:**

```
       A      B    C
0    1.0    2.0  NaN
1    NaN  500.0  NaN
2    NaN    6.0  NaN
3  300.0    8.0  5.0
4  400.0  106.0  NaN
```

Comment: you absolute wizard @shubham-sharma! Just trying to get my head around this and getting it to play nice with my multindex, but I believe you've done it and its relatively instant in terms of performance on the large dataset, compared to my attempts.

Comment: Very nice solution indeed! I will reuse it for sure :) I just wanted to say that this approach is based on the `.first()` behavior, which skips the `NaN` values. As discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6732), it is not certain this will always be the case, even though it appears to be the most probable scenario.

Comment: Thanks @Andrea For pointing out the link, that will be definitely useful for the OP in understanding the behaviour of `.first`.

Comment: When you say 'not always be the case', do you mean future releases of pandas? Otherwise, I personally don't see anything in that ticket that gives some inconsistent behaviour. If it's future releases, then maybe first(dropna=True) should be explicitly added to Shubhams solution. Thanks